# Is there an efficient way for getting the rarest role of a member discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have implemented a feature that shows people their rarest role (the role that the least people have). I did it by looping through each of their roles and checking how many people have the role. As it turns out, if you have over like 50 roles, it delays the bots response visibly, so I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing the same thing. My code is here:

```
const rolesOfMember = member._roles
for(const role in rolesOfMember) {
  var membersHavingCurrentRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get(rolesOfMember[role]).members.size
  if(membersHavingCurrentRole < membersHavingRarestRole) {
    membersHavingRarestRole = membersHavingCurrentRole
    rarestRoleID = rolesOfMember[role]
  } else if(membersHavingCurrentRole == membersHavingRarestRole) {
    var rarestRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get(rarestRoleID)
    var currentRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get(rolesOfMember[role])
    if(rarestRole.comparePositionTo(currentRole) < 0) {
      membersHavingRarestRole = membersHavingCurrentRole
      rarestRoleID = rolesOfMember[role]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way to simplify your code would be to not have to call `message.guild.roles.cache.get()` 3 or so times for every role that the member has, especially if they're going to have 50+ roles. In fact, we could eliminate the need for your `member._roles` object entirely, and therefore eliminate the need for the `for/in` loop. Here's an example (tested and works):

```
var rolesOfMember = message.member.roles.cache;
var rarestRole = rolesOfMember.sort((roleA, roleB) => roleA.members.size - roleB.members.size).first();
var rarestRoleID = rarestRole.id;
```

In this example, I first get the Collection of all of the roles that the member has. Then, I use the `Collection.sort()` method to sort the roles based on how many members have each role in the guild (from least to greatest, so in other words from rarest to most common). Since the first role in this sorted Collection will be the rarest role that the user has, I simply call `Collection.first()` on the sorted Collection in order to retrieve the first and rarest `Role`. From there, you can use `rarestRole` however you'd like, I simply retrieve the role's ID and store it in a variable in my example.

You can also alter the sorting function however you'd like in order to consider the case in which two roles have the same amount of people who have them.

Relevant resources:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=members
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=sort

Comment: Turns out this method takes even longer to sort it, no idea why. But thanks for help :)

Comment: Interesting, I would have expected it to be faster. When I tested it out with about 25 roles, it seemed to work instantly. But oh well, unfortunately I have no idea how to make the process any more efficient. Np :)